# How to add System.Web in a Windows Form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have Imports System.Web as well as the System.Web referenced, and my target framework is set to .NET Framework 4, however I get the following error when I try to use System.Web:

> Error 17  'Web' is not a member of 'System'.

Is there something that I am missing?

**Edit for more clarification:**
Here's a code snippet:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web               
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI           
Imports System.Text             
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Net
```

Inside of a class...

```
If (Not File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path))) Then

        File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close()

     End If
```

Error I get:

> Error 17  'Web' is not a member of 'System'.

**What have I done?**

- Referenced System.Web in Project>Add reference
- Changed target framework to .NET Framework 4

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you have a bigger issue...even if you add the reference...you don't have an httpcontext in a windows form...you don't need the mappath function...what's your underlying real goal here and we can help you resolve it

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Sorry, that class can be dropped (I realistically don't need mappath anymore). However, I still get a similar error for another class where I'm using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, and getting the error Error 48 'AppSettings' is not a member of 'ProjectName.System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'.

Answer (score 2):

Likely your project is referencing the *client* .NET Framework profile. You will need to target the *full* .NET Framework profile.

Comment: @JosephB theres a client profile which doesn't include asp.net and the full profile which does. you have to make sure you specify the full profile.